# Prime number algorithm stops working after certain point

Tags: python, algorithm, sieve

Here is my prime number finding algorithm -- it works great (and very fast) up until the limit is set above 173, then it starts throwing

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I don't understand why this is when it works absolutely fine up until the limit is 174 or above -- here is my code.

```
def primefinder(limit):
    primes = [2, 3]
    for i in range(1, (limit / 6 + 1)):
        primes.append(6 * i - 1)
        primes.append(6 * i + 1)

    for i in primes[:]:
        if i > 24:
            for x in primes:
                if x <= i ** 0.5:
                    if i % x == 0:
                        primes.remove(i)
                        continue
                else:
                    break

    if limit % 6 == 0:
        primes.remove(primes[-1])
    return primes
```

Comment: Is this algorithm based on some well-known prime-finding methodology? Can you comment your code and/or reference a source that describes how the algorithm works? Sticking a println right before the primes.remove() and printing the primes and i might help you understand what is going wrong.

Comment: It fails because you arrive at the first number with more than one prime factor. Any minimal amount of debugging should have revealed the problem.. So go do that

Comment: Thanks M4rtini -- I just fixed it

Comment: @RobbieBarrat Good, you can then post an answer yourself and accept that http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @SPKoder the algorithm is based on the statement that all prime numbers are of the form of 6k+1or 6k-1. Which is widely used to check if the number is prime. But not all results 6k+1 or 6k-1 are prime number, for example: 6*4+1 = 25 (5*5). So the author uses 6k+1 formula to generate the list of prime candidates and then remove numbers of the type x*x.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go - You don't want to have the print in there, thats just to show what's going on.

```
def primefinder(limit):
    primes = [2, 3]
    for i in range(4, limit):
        if (prime(i)):
            primes.append(i)
            print (i)

    return primes

def prime(number):
    oldnum = number
    factor = 1
    while number > 1:
        factor += 1
        if number % factor == 0:
            if 1 < factor < oldnum:
                return False
            number //= factor
    return True

primefinder(200000)
```

Comment: If all you're gonna do is give a working, although horribly slow, prime finder. You might as well just link to any of the numerous prime finder questions already answered.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n

Comment: For limit 100k. This runs in about 1,5 minutes. OP code runs in 3 seconds (with the minor fix needed). Pure python answer in linked post runs in under 5ms

Comment: As the comment above said; this isn't even the same algorithm -- it doesn't work anything like my program. I know I did a pretty horrible job of explaining how it worked (I actually didn't at all), but this doesn't even attempt to use the same method.

Comment: Yes that would help haha, please explain why and how you need it